# add one column value in end of another column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|    city        |      city2     |   state  |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|     abc        |     ghe        |    NY    |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|     def        |     jkl        |    NY    |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
```

and want result like this in which value of `city` and `city2` combine in one column `combined`

```
+---------------------+
|      combined       |
+---------------------+
|        abc          |
+---------------------+
|        def          |
+---------------------+
|        ghe          |
+---------------------+
|        jkl          |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: What would you like to happen if state OR has city = abc?

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `union all`;

```
select city as combined from t
union all
select city2 from t;
```

If you want unique values, then use `union` rather than `union all`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT city FROM myTable
UNION
SELECT city2 FROM myTable
```